# How to extract date and time from a String Timestamp in java

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime

I am getting  date and time as a `String` `TIMESTAMP` from MySQL from a server in such a format:

```
2014-02-15 05:18:08
```

What I want is to extract the Date in `DD-MM-YYYY` format and the time in `HH:MM:SS AM/PM` format. Also the timezone of this timestamp is different and I want it in Indian Timezone(IST).

Remember the `timestamp` is of `String` datatype.

Comment: Use a `SimpleDateFormat` instance for parsing.

Comment: By the way, avoid 3-letter time zone codes. They are neither standardized nor unique. Your use of `IST` can mean "Irish Standard Time" as well as "India Standard Time". Instead, use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) such as "Asia/Kolkata".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.TimeZone`

Which timezone the date string is in? Replace the below `UTC` timezone with that timezone

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = sdf.parse("2014-02-15 05:18:08");

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
String dateStr = sdf2.format(date); // Output: 15-02-2014 10:48:08 AM
```

**Note:** In which format the hour is in (24 hour/ 12 hour) in your input string? The above example assumes that it is in 24 hour format because there in no AM/PM info in the input string.

If the input string is also in 12 hour format then your input string should mention AM/PM info also such as `2014-02-15 05:18:08 PM`. In that case, modify the `sdf` to `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a")`

========================
**Edited:** =====================

To answer your next question in comment "How to extract date and time separately"...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
sdfDate.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
sdfTime.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

String dateStr = sdfDate.format(date);
String timeStr = sdfTime.format(date);
```

Comment: Thanks Yatendra for helping.It worked flawlessly. I am new to java actually. Can you please tell me how can I extract Date and Time individually as a String ? Actually I am programming for android and I want to display Date and Time in its own textviews.

Comment: Ok figured it out myself by just altering the format string. Thanks man it helped me a lot. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The accepted [answer by Yatendra Goel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21796648/642706) is correct.

## Joda-Time

For fun, here's the same kind of code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

Note that [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). The team advises migration to java.time. See [my other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39046312/642706) for [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) code.

FYI… India is five *and a half* hours ahead of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT. Hence the thirty minute difference in the outputs below.

```
String input = "2014-02-15 05:18:08";
input = input.replace( " ", "T" ); // Replace space in middle with a "T" to get ISO 8601 format.

// Parse input as DateTime in UTC/GMT.
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( input, DateTimeZone.UTC );
// Adjust to India time.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTime = dateTimeUtc.withZone( timeZone );

// Using "en" for English here because (a) it is irrelevant in our case, and (b) I don't know any Indian language codes.
java.util.Locale localeIndiaEnglish = new Locale( "en", "IN" ); // ( language code, country code );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "SS" ).withLocale( localeIndiaEnglish ).withZone( timeZone );
String output = formatter.print( dateTime );

DateTimeFormatter formatterDateOnly = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" ).withLocale( localeIndiaEnglish ).withZone( timeZone );
DateTimeFormatter formatterTimeOnly = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "hh:mm:ss a" ).withLocale( localeIndiaEnglish ).withZone( timeZone );
String dateOnly = formatterDateOnly.print( dateTime );
String timeOnly = formatterTimeOnly.print( dateTime );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
System.out.println( "dateOnly: " + dateOnly );
System.out.println( "timeOnly: " + timeOnly );
```

When run…

```
input: 2014-02-15T05:18:08
dateTimeUtc: 2014-02-15T05:18:08.000Z
dateTime: 2014-02-15T10:48:08.000+05:30
output: 15/2/14 10:48 AM
dateOnly: 15-02-2014
timeOnly: 10:48:08 AM
```

Comment: @RafiAbro Glad to help. But be aware that the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). See [my other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39046312/642706) for *java.time*.

Comment: oh, what will happen to those applications in which I have used joda-Time..

Comment: @RafiAbro Joda-Time continues to be actively maintained with bug fixes and updates to it bundled [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). But no further development of features. When convenient, you should rework your apps to use *java.time* classes. But not urgent. The transition is fairly easy as the two projects share the same concepts and the same leader, Stephen Colebourne.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SimpleDateFormat like:-

```
String s = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(yourTimestamp);
```

For more info 
[SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2014-02-15 05:18:08".replace( " " , "T" ) ).atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime();
```

## Use objects, not strings

You should be retrieving date-time values from your database as date-time objects rather than Strings.

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes in Java 8 and later supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes as well as the 3rd-party Joda-Time library.

- The `java.sql.Timestamp` class is replaced by `Instant`.
- The `java.sql.Date` class is replaced by `LocalDate`.
- The `java.sql.Time` class is replaced by `LocalTime`.
  -

## Parsing String

If you are stuck with such a String, parse it using a java.time classes. The other Answers are using the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Those are now legacy, and should be avoided.

Your input string is almost in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Merely replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2014-02-15 05:18:08".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

## `LocalDateTime`

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` as the string lacks any info about [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or time zone.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

I will assume the value in your input String was intended to be a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone. So adjust into UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

You asked for this to be adjusted into the [India time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India) zone, which is five and a half hours ahead of UTC.

The `atZoneSameInstant` means the resulting `ZonedDateTime` represents the very same simultaneous moment as the `OffsetDateTime`. The two are different only in that they view that same moment through two different lenses of [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z );
```

## `LocalDate` & `LocalTime`

If you want to work with the date portion and time-of-day portion separately, extract each as a `Local…`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime();
```

## Generating String representation

The `toString` method on the classes all generate a String representation using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. To use other formats, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. Search Stack Overflow for many examples and discussions.

The easiest way is let the class automatically localize for you. Specify a `Locale` for the desired human language and the desired cultural norms to decide issues such as capitalization, abbreviation, and such.

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "en" , "IN" ); // English language, India cultural norms.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

you can use DATE_FORMAT(date,format).

in your case it'd be something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%e-%c-%Y') FROM table WHERE...
```

-edit: the code above will return your timestamp as : "DD-MM-YYYY".

timestamp being your mySQL field (in other words: column).

for other format options I'd recommend you to have a quick look at:
[DATE_FORMAT options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)